# How to configure port to port forwarding on ASA 5512-X?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Below is the config. The port redirection is working, but the range of the ports and other ports permitted in the access-list are not opening:

```
object network TEST_PUBLIC_IP

host 10.10.10.10

object-group service PROD_101 tcp
port-object eq 8443
port-object eq 922
port-object eq ssh
port-object eq https
port-object range 8000 8200

object network TEST_PRIVATE_IP

host 1.1.1.1.
nat (PRODUCTION,OUTSIDE) static TEST_PUBLIC_IP service tcp 8085 www

access-list Outside_IN extended permit tcp any object TEST_PRIVATE_IP object-group PROD_101

access-group Outside_IN in interface outside
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the ASA code 8.3+, you need to specify the real IP address *and* the real port in the inbound outside access list. Based on the configuration you provided, if you add:

```
object-group service PROD_101 tcp
port-object eq www
```

It should fix your problem.

EDIT: Working configuration for the other ports

```
object service TCP-SOURCE-22 
 service tcp source eq 22 

nat (PRODUCTION,OUTSIDE) source static TEST_PRIVATE_IP TEST_PUBLIC_IP service TCP-SOURCE-22 TCP-SOURCE-22 

object service TCP-SOURCE-8000_8200 
 service tcp source range 8000 8200 

nat (PRODUCTION,OUTSIDE) source static TEST_PRIVATE_IP TEST_PUBLIC_IP service TCP-SOURCE-8000_8200 TCP-SOURCE-8000_8200
```

Comment: Thanks Josh,The redirection from www of the domain name to port 8085 is working perfectly. However, the challenge i have is that i cannot ssh into the server and also the port range 8000 8200 are not opening.

Comment: Does the entire 8000-8200 range need to be forwarded to port 80 on the 10.10.10.10 server? Also are the other ports listed in your service group changed upon translation? Let me know and I will write up the NAT statements.

Comment: Thanks so much Josh, someone assisted with solution that resolved the challenge. He designed NAT for both SSH and port ranges. Its working perfectly....Thanks so much for taken your time to read and get back to me.

Comment: Not a problem. If you want I can include the NAT statements in the answer to help someone else if they come across this.

Comment: Ok... Below is the config that i added that worked for both ssh and port range access to the server.                                                                 object service TCP-SOURCE-22
      service tcp source eq 22
nat (PRODUCTION,OUTSIDE) source static TEST_PRIVATE_IP TEST_PUBLIC_IP  service TCP-SOURCE-22 TCP-SOURCE-22

object service TCP-SOURCE-8000_8200
       service tcp source range 8000 8200
 nat (PRODUCTION,OUTSIDE) source static TEST_PRIVATE_IP TEST_PUBLIC_IP  service TCP-SOURCE-8000_8200 TCP-SOURCE-8000_8200